# Alternatives to String SDK (http://string.co). What to use instead

Tags: ios, objective-c, computer-vision

I came across tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/40870/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-marker-tracking.
It uses String SDK, but that SDK is no longer active.

What are some alternatives ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find a list of alternative AR SDKs along with a comparison of each here http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks  From what I can tell this list is pretty active and updated frequently.